# Vue.js Vuetify checkbox to chipgroup

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Currently have a checkbox implementation to filter down search items but want make use of the chip group component instead.

Checkbox:

```
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="assetFilters"
    label="image"
    value="image"
  />
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="assetFilters"
    label="video"
    value="video"
  />
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="assetFilters"
    label="pdf"
    value="pdf"
  />
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="assetFilters"
    label="link"
    value="link"
  />
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="assetFilters"
    label="text"
    value="text"
  />
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="assetFilters"
    label="powerpoint"
    value="powerpoint"
  />
```

Chip group:

```
    <v-chip-group
      v-model="assetFilters"
      multiple
    >
      <v-chip
        v-for="item in assetFilters"
        :key="item"
        outlined
        filter
      >
        {{ item }}
      </v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
```

What have I done wrong for this chip group implimantation?

```
  data () {
    return {
      assetFilters: ['powerpoint', 'pdf', 'image', 'video', 'link', 'text'],
```

Finally the watch which updates:

```
  watch: {
    assetFilters () {
      console.log('asset filter change')
      this.search()
    }
  },
```

Comment: You need separate field like `selectedItems` as `v-model` for `chip-group`.

Comment: Thanks @MatJ . Could you please do a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a variable in data property to store selected chips:

```
data () {
    return {
      assetFilters: ['powerpoint', 'pdf', 'image', 'video', 'link', 'text'],
      selectedFilters: []
    }
}
```

Note that because you are using `multiple` props in `v-chip-group`, `selectedFilters` should be array.

```
<v-chip-group
      v-model="selectedFilters"
      multiple
      @change="handleChange"
>
      <v-chip
        v-for="item in assetFilters"
        :key="item"
        outlined
        filter
        :value="item"
      >
        {{ item }}
      </v-chip>
</v-chip-group>
```

Then you can define `@change` event to track the value of `selectedFilters`:

```
methods: {
    handleChange() {
      console.log('asset filter change', this.selectedFilters)
      this.search()
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I store the value rather than the index?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you can send `:value="item"` prop for each `v-chip` tag. I've just updated my answer.